# installing openvpn on raspberry pi3

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, vpn

i try to create a free vpn client of raspberry pi 3 to hide my ip address when i connect to the internet.to do that i install an openvpn from vpnbook.com on my rasbian stretch OS. this is what i do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openvpn
cd /etc/openvpn/
sudo wget https://certificate-vpnbook
sudo unzip certificate
sudo nano password.txt
vpnbook
*******
```

i run this command:

`sudo openvpn vpnbook-pl226-udp53.ovpn`
and get this error:

```
WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/password.txt' is group or others accessible
penVPN 2.4.0 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] 
[EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 18 2017
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018, LZO 2.08
WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See 
http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET
Socket Buffers: R=[163840->163840] S=[163840->163840]
UDP link local: (not bound)
UDP link remote: [AF_INET]51.68.152.226:53
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check 
your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

i also change the DNS address in this file: /etc/openvpn/server.conf from google dns server:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

to 
   `push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"`

i search the warning and the result are about vpn server and mine is vpn client.
i don't know how to solve my problem. i appreciate your help.

Comment: The first error shows that the password file is readable by other than the user running openvpn,  You need to make it root readable only (`chmod 600`)

Comment: If you're looking for anonymity (instead of encryption security), you may wish to consider using your RPi as a Tor router. There was a good Q&A on that subject posted only recently... here's a link to [make your RPi a Tor router](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92295/how-to-make-raspberry-pi-a-tor-router-with-all-kind-of-network-setup-using-syste)

Comment: thank you but i think vpn could be more helpful.

Comment: hello @Ingo. your post is being mentioned here. i want to ask you about raspberry pi as a Tor client. i already turn my raspberry pi to a tor router but i want to know how can i use raspi as a tor client with Ethernet cable?i appreciate your help.