# How to configure TOR on RaspAp?

Tags: networking

having problems with installing TOR on RaspAp application, could anyone take a look at it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EnAE.jpg

1# shows that nothing opens when i press "Save settings"
2# picture is after i press "start TOR"
3# and 4# are mine settings of TOR

thank you so much, regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Raspberry Pi a Tor router with all kind of network setup using systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92295/how-to-make-raspberry-pi-a-tor-router-with-all-kind-of-network-setup-using-syste) or [Problem: Tor Router with a Wifi to Ethernet Bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95568/79866) or [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95568/79866](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95568/79866).

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of text. I don't read them. In addition yours are unreadable. Please paste the text direct into the question. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.