# Configure my Raspberry Pi 4 B to become a Tor-powered Hotspot

Tags: networking, pi-4, openwrt, encryption

I want to be able to connect from my computer to my pi to automatically connect to tor. This would entail that when I can technically use Tor from any browser on my computer. I have tried methods using OpenWrt and using Raspbian, but they simply don't work.

Any ideas?

**Update** with info from comment:
I want my pi to be a bridge from my computer to my router. When I configure that (Using this article:(gremaudpi.emf-informatique.ch/create-a-bridged-access-point-with-raspberry-pi-and-openwrt/) I cannot log back onto the pi after i change the lan ip address

Comment: `but they simply don't work.`, any errors messages ?

Comment: no. For example, In rasbian, it would require editing some files, but it would do nothing. and in OpenWrt, if I tried to make a connection, i couldn't get back on to Luci.

Comment: Add more information about what exactly wants to be able? You mention OpenWrt, so, if you wanna connect the wireless clients to tor, check this link out: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/tor/client

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I first want my pi to be a bridge from my computer to my router. When I configure that (Using this article:(gremaudpi.emf-informatique.ch/create-a-bridged-access-point-with-raspberry-pi-and-openwrt/) I cannot log back onto the pi after i change the lan ip address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to configure a Tor proxy that will act like an internet router but connect to the Tor network instead. You can use the `tor.service` with the big advantage that it does not need a specific underlaying network configuration. If you have a network interface that routes traffic to the internet you can use it for the tor proxy. You can find an example at [How to make Raspberry Pi a Tor router with all kind of network setup using systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92296/79866).

You have a Raspberry Pi 4B with a port for wired connections so for the underlaying network configuration you can use a simple ethernet cable to connect to your internet router. You don't need an USB to wired ethernet dongle (you say "*usb to ethernet cable*"). This is the best solution because it has an simpler setup and is less error prone. You can follow this setup: [access point (wlan0) with wired uplink (eth0)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).

If you cannot connect by wire to your internet router then you can use an [access point (ap0) with wifi uplink (wlan0)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). This can be configured with the on-board WiFi device only. You also do not need an additional USB to WiFi dongle.

Comment: for my case, should i use:
1. access point (ap0) with wifi uplink (wlan0), wlan repeater with on-board wifi - section: Setup wifi repeater
2. access point (wlan0) with wired uplink (eth0), wlan repeater with wired uplink - section: Setting up an access point and with eth0, with routing
3. access point (wlan1) with wifi uplink (wlan0), wlan repeater with additional USB/wifi dongle
4. wired subnet (eth1) with uplink (eth0), router with two wired ports.

I do not have an usb to ethernet cable

Comment: @BigBird I have updated the answer.

Comment: this is a little off-topic but i am doing a project for school and i want to interview you. Here are the questions: 1. How long have you used Raspberry Pi(s)? 2. Do you enjoy working with them? What is the hardest part? 3. How did you learn about Raspberry? 4. What skills/talents do you need to understand the pi? 5. Would you recommend a student pursuing his career in this kind of work? how would a student begin a career in this kind of work? Thank you, and I hope you answer soon, because it is due tomorrow.

Comment: @BigBird Sorry, just read your questions, it seems a bit too late. And there are questions that cannot be answered with some words in a comment... A forum may be a better place to ask but I don't know if https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ is the right place? Maybe at section "Education"?