# Tor Router Raspberry pi 4 Access-Point no internet connection

Tags: raspbian, wifi, linux, wireless

I am trying to create a Tor Router with a Raspberry Pi 4, the newest raspbian version, the inbuild Wlan0-Card for the Access-Point and a external Edimax Usb Wlan1-Card to get a internet connection.

I am successfull in creating the Access-Point i can connect to it with my "Galaxy S9" and i can surf in the Internet with my real ip Address.

But i can not get the tor part to work because, as soon as i start tor and add the iptables for tor i have no internet connection anymore on my "Galaxy S9".

Here are my steps which i did:

## CREATING THE ACCESS-POINT:

## separated wpa_supplicant configurations by interface

`$ cd /etc/wpa_supplicant
$ sudo cp wpa_supplicant.conf wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
$ sudo cp wpa_supplicant.conf wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf`

## added my wifi ssid and pass

`wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf`

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    psk="MYPlainTextPassword"
}

## installed hostapd and dnsmasq

`$ sudo apt-get install hostapd dnsmasq`

## edited "/etc/dhcpcd.conf"

`interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.179.1/24`

## edited "/etc/dnsmasq.conf"

`interface=wlan0
no-dhcp-interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.179.10,192.168.179.150,24h
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8`

## edited "/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"

`interface=wlan0
ssid=TorWifi
channel=9
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=TorWifi123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
wpa_group_rekey=86400`

## edited "/etc/default/hostapd"

`DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`

## edited "/etc/sysctl.conf"

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

## added iptables to test the Access-Point

`$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT`

## Access-Point Successfully created and working

`$ sudo systemctl start dnsmasq
$ sudo systemctl start hostapd`

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

## TOR CONFIGURATION:

## installed tor

`$ sudo apt-get install tor`

## edited "/etc/tor/torrc"

```
# Transparent proxy port
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.179.1
# Explicit SOCKS port for applications.
SocksPort 9050
# Have Tor run in the background
RunAsDaemon 1
# Only ever run as a client. Do not run as a relay or an exit.
ClientOnly
# Ensure resolution of .onion and .exit domains happen through Tor.
AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
# Serve DNS responses
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 192.168.179.1
```

## added iptables

`$ sudo iptables -F
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040`

Comment: For a tested setup here you can look [How to make Raspberry Pi a Tor router with all kind of network setup using systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92296/79866).

Comment: Welcome.  I approved your edit from (what I hope was!) your duplicate account, but if you have lost your original login credentials trying to do this here is going to be a waste of time -- you can't comment or interact, so I have closed this temporarily.  If you can access the original account, just ping @goldilocks here and I will re-open this.  Otherwise, see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)* or else just re-post this question using the new account *and don't loose the credentials, you need them.*